# Auditing Linux: tell me to what IPs a connection was established

Tags: linux, networking, audit

I need a command, or something that runs as a cron job, that logs what IPs my machine is communicating with, what ports, and what process did it.

Comment: Running something as a `cron` job means you will miss many connections. I'd suggest learning the ropes of `auditd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Socket Stat:

```
ss -p
```

You might want to explore `ss` manpage for some more options, like `-r` to resolve ip addresses to domain name:

```
ss -pr
```

Another good tool is `netstat`, but I found `ss` command line invocation to be simpler with respect to the result you want.

Comment: `ss` is a linux specific utility. `netstat` is more widely available (but the options differ depending on OS).

Comment: Right! Anyway, the OP was looking for a Linux solution, so `ss` is fine.

Answer (score 2):

There are many tools and ways to do this but this is probably what you're looking for:

http://www.tcpdump.org/